# Quarkus Configure Metrics for SmallRye Fault Tolerance

Tags: quarkus, micrometer, smallrye

My Quarkus application is using Micrometer and Smallrye Fault Tolarance extensions, and I appreciate the fact that using the @CircuitBreaker annotation automatically adds metrics. However, the format and labels are kind of ugly and would make maintaining and operational dashboards and monitoring a pain as they seem to be autogenerated based on the package and class. Example: refactoring or moving them would basically break Prometheus query.

Is it possible to configure this with Quarkus?

This is what the metrics look like out of the box

`ft_some_really_long_package_name_ClassName_methodName_circuitbreaker_halfOpen_total{} 0`

What I would like to have is something like this

`circuitbreaker_halfOpen_total{package="com.somepackage", class="SomeClass", method="SomeMethod"} 0`

Comment: This is not possible to configure, but MicroProfile Fault Tolerance 3.0, which will be released soon, changes metrics very much in line with your suggestion. SmallRye Fault Tolerance will implement that in version 5.0, which will be released shortly after MicroProfile Fault Tolerance 3.0 is released (all the implementation work is finished, we're just waiting for final release of the specification).

Answer (score 2):

hmmm. You should be able to do this with a MeterFilter, I think, but getting the string munging right (to split package/classname/methodName)

https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer#using-meterfilter-to-configure-metrics

```
@Produces
@Singleton
public MeterFilter renameFaultToleranceMetrics() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
            if (id.getName().endsWith("circuitbreaker_halfOpen_total")) {
                // Do things here to make a new list of tags based on string munging
              List<Tag> tags = ...
              return id.withName("circuitbreaker_halfOpen_total").replaceTags(tags);
            }
            return id;
        }
    };
}
```

An example is here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/integration-tests/micrometer-mp-metrics/src/main/java/io/quarkus/it/micrometer/mpmetrics/RenameMeterFilterProducer.java